# Problem with negative date on iPad and not on simulator

Tags: cocoa, ipad, date, nsdateformatter

I'm working on an history application so I need to cope with date before and after JC.

I'm trying to parse a string with the form "01/01/-200" but it returns a null date while it's working with "01/01/200".

Here is my code :

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/y"]; // @TODO Get negative date
[dateFormatter setLenient:NO];

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
return date;
```

I also try using with the form "01/01/200 BC" `setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/y G"` but I can't make it work neither. 
As mvds suggests in his answer, I tried the format "01/01/200 BC" on the simulator, and it's working... **the problem only occurs on my iPad** (version 3.2.1)

Do you have an idea how to do this properly ?

Comment: There might be 3rd party date libraries that can handle BCE dates, but I don't know of any, so I would imagine that if the native date library can't handle it, you may have to write your own Date wrapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the trick.
The problem is that my iPad is in French so the Era has a different format :

- BC is "av. J.-C."
- AD is "ap. J.-C."

So I just had to change my XML file to get the correct format when parsing.

In order to display my date in the AD-BC format, I just convert it afterward :

```
+ (NSString*) convertIntoBCADString:(NSString*) originalString 
{
    NSString* newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"av. J.-C." withString:@"BC"];
    return [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ap. J.-C." withString:@"AD"]; 
}
```

Comment: For reference, issues like this can be resolved with the following code: `NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; [formatter setLocale:locale];`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/y G"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/01/200 BC"];
NSLog(@"refdate %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
date = [date addTimeInterval:24*3600*365*2];
NSLog(@"2 years later %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

which outputs:

```
refdate 01/01/200 BC
2 years later 01/01/198 BC
```

This is on 3.2, iPad simulator, so not the most recent SDK, but iPad nonetheless. Do you get different results, running this?

Comment: It's really strange. Your code works on the simulator but not on my iPad...
I'll check if it has something to do with my iPad's setting or code versions.
Thanks for your help. I think you've spotted out the problem.